# Counter gets incremented twice

Tags: javascript

I am writing a simple JavaScript game in which the user clicks on a div that plays sounds and if they guess the animal sound correct, a counter keeps track of their score and increments.
It works, but if the same sound is played again and the user guesses it increments the counter with two not one and sometimes even by three and I can't figure out why and how to fix it, here is my HTML:

```
<div id="counter">Score:<span id="counter-score"> 0</span> </div>
```

and here is the JavaScript code:

```
var sounds = [
    {
        animalType: 'horse',
        sound: new Audio('../sounds/Horse-neigh.mp3')
    },
    {
        animalType: 'bear',
        sound: new Audio('../sounds/grizzlybear.mp3')
    },
    {
        animalType: 'goat',
        sound: new Audio('../sounds/Goat-noise.mp3'),
    }
];

var player = document.getElementById('player');
var enteredWord = document.getElementById('entered-word');
var counter = document.getElementById('counter-score');

startGame();


function startGame() {
    player.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var sound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length)];
        var currentSound = sound.animalType;
        sound['sound'].play();

        enteredWord.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
            if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                if (enteredWord.value === currentSound) {
                    counter.textContent++;
                }
            } else {

            }
        });
    });
}
```

Why does it happen like that?

I tried using the += operator but it gives the same result.

Comment: how often do you start the game,  and how often the event gets an listener with it?

Comment: Everytime you click, a new keydown event is added. So after two clicks, keydown will be called twice. move the keydown event outside of the click.

Comment: In your function try Add and remove event listener...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Ibu said in comments, each time the click event occur, a new event listener is added to `keydown` event.

You should extract the `enteredWord.addEventListener` part outside of `player.addEventListener` callback, like so:

```
function startGame() {
  var currentSound;
  player.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var sound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
    currentSound = sound.animalType;
    sound['sound'].play();
  })


  enteredWord.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
    if(event.key === 'Enter') {
      if(enteredWord.value === currentSound) {
        counter.textContent ++;
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: True, but I can't access the currentSound variable that way

Comment: @MurrayJohnson my bad, I just put the `currentSound` variable declaration inside parent function to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you replace your code with this one, I think the key-down event is executing twice so you are getting this issue.

```
enteredWord.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {        
     if( (e.keyCode ==13) && (enteredWord.value === currentSound)){
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();         
          counter.textContent ++;
      }
  })
```

Comment: Hi @MurrayJohnson can you try e.stopImmediatePropagation();